# Get field of struct pointer if not nil, otherwise default value

Tags: go, reflection

I'm looking for a function that would reduce the redundancy in accessing a member of a struct pointer in Go.  It should perform the member access if the pointer is not `nil`, or return a default value otherwise.  It should be functionally equivalent to:

```golang
var ptr *MyStruct
var result any
if ptr != nil {
    result = ptr.MyField
} else {
    result = sql.NullFloat64{}
}
```

In principle, this pattern comes from the `orElse` of optionals in many other languages.  The use case is to extract a field from a nested protobuf message and stuff it into a SQL query.  The resulting function looks like the following:

```golang
func GetFieldOrElse(v any, fn string, or any) any {
    segments := strings.Split(fn, ".")
    r := reflect.ValueOf(v)
    for _, field := range segments {
        if r.IsNil() {
            return or
        }
        r = reflect.Indirect(r).FieldByName(field)
    }
    return r.Interface()
}

// pi is a protobuf message and ExtraParams is a nested message inside `pi`
GetFieldOrElse(pi.ExtraParams, "Make", sql.NullString{})
GetFieldOrElse(pi.ExtraParams, "Model", sql.NullString{})
GetFieldOrElse(pi.ExtraParams, "LensModel", sql.NullString{})
GetFieldOrElse(pi.ExtraParams, "Aperture.Numerator", sql.NullInt64{})
GetFieldOrElse(pi.ExtraParams, "Aperture.Denominator", sql.NullInt64{})
```

I tried to look for a compile-time solution (i.e. without reflection) but failed.  Is this the idiomatic way of achieving this goal?

Comment: Reflection works, generics could work too and several copies of the initial function work too. Do what fits your needs.

Comment: @Volker can you show me how generics would work in this case?  I'm not sure how to specify the field name without putting it into a string, since Go does not have pointer-to-members like C++...

Comment: @Volker I had the impression that reflection is really expensive and wanted to avoid using it whenever possible, not sure if this is one of those cases

Comment: Reflection is not „really expensive“ especially not until you **measured**.